# Ansible: how to execute Windows exe installer with a wizard?

Tags: ansible, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to install Visual C++ redistributable on Windows server.

This package is distributed as `vc_redist.x64.exe` file. The installer is a wizard whith few choices.

I've looked throuhg [Ansible windows modules](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/list_of_windows_modules.html) and found nothing applicable.

How can I handle such cases by Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an Ansible problem. Neither Ansible nor any other automation tool (and especially remote ones) will allow you to proceed with GUI apps.

When you are facing such a task, you should first google for "*Visual C++ redistributable* ***unattended install***". It will give you plenty of ways to do it.

Or install [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install), choose the right package from the repository [vcredist](https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=vcredist) and use the Ansible `win_chocolatey` task to make sure it is installed, for example:

```
- name: Ensure vcredist2015 package is installed
  win_chocolatey:
    name: vcredist2015
```

Comment: Im using this OP to hopefuly find some answers for a 3rd party app that has no silent switches for the 2nd and 3rd popup of chain executeables it installs.  we only have wizard options.  So, it would be great to see part of this answer what ansible has to offer to read content, and click buttons, so we can try to program something out to automate this instal.  Any suggestions  for an ansible workflow for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Argument Parameter in your playbook and set that to /q for silent install

name: Install 2012 Redistributable C++

```
win_package:

  path: Input path to EXE File

  product_id: 'Input Product ID here'

  state: present

  arguments: /q
```